# How to explain the name of the author of a work which is a base for a performance

Tags: phrase-requests

Could you please help me with the following:

The context is a printed information about a play. For example:

```
              name of the play: .........
              playwright: ...............
              director: .................
              cast: .....................
              etc.
```

And now I want to say that the performance or play is based on, uses motives from the famous work of an author. For example based on Chekhov's work, or Dario Fo or another. And how do I say that correctly?

after Dario Fo?
by Dario Fo?
based on Dario Fo?
with motive from Dario Fo?

Comment: One question mark per question is plenty.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic (request for writing advice).

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by or Based on.  Depends on the actual meaning you want to convey.

Answer (score 2):

You normally cite the *work* that it is based on, followed by "by *author*".

> based on "The Lady with the Dog" by Anton Chekov

or, leaving off the name of the work,

> based on a story by Anton Chekov

Saying "inspired by" means that it is not as literally "based on" the original work; more liberties are taken with plot/characters/etc, or maybe it's not even the same story, but an extension using the same plot device, characters, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you could say ***adaptation of*** or ***adapted from***

> [adapted](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adapted?s=t)
>
> to make suitable to requirements or conditions; adjust or modify fittingly: *He adapted the novel for movies.*
>
> to fit, change, or modify to suit a new or different purpose: *to adapt a play for use in schools*